# What is a good way to design and build a task scheduling system with lots of recurring tasks?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, cron, queue, scheduled-tasks

Imagine you're building something like a monitoring service, which has thousands of tasks that need to be executed in given time interval, independent of each other. This could be individual servers that need to be checked, or backups that need to be verified, or just anything at all that could be scheduled to run at a given interval.

You can't just schedule the tasks via cron though, because when a task is run it needs to determine when it's supposed to run the next time. For example:

- schedule server uptime check every 1 minute
- first time it's checked the server is down, schedule next check in 5 seconds
- 5 seconds later the server is available again, check again in 5 seconds
- 5 seconds later the server is still available, continue checking at 1 minute interval

A naive solution that came to mind is to simply have a *worker* that runs every second or so, checks all the pending jobs and executes the ones that need to be executed. But how would this work if the number of jobs is something like 100 000? It might take longer to check them all than it is the ticking interval of the  worker, and the more tasks there will be, the higher the poll interval.

Is there a better way to design a system like this? Are there any hidden challenges in implementing this, or any algorithms that deal with this sort of a problem?

Comment: My guess would be that you should call low-level OS functions to schedule tasks; they're probably most efficient in invoking them at the right time. E.g. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at. Beyond that I'd probably involve queues and workers to manage scalability.

Comment: It's highly unlikely to take more than 1 second to process a 100000 item list. You need something approaching 10000000 for it to be a problem. Besides, once you reach more than 86400 tasks it will be more efficient to simply have a list of 86400 seconds (number of seconds in a day) and attach your tasks to which second they need to run on.

Comment: @slebetman: And how will that work when the next run time for a given task is sometime tomorrow--or the next day, or a week from now? Would you allocate an array of 86400 items every day for the next year, just to schedule "audit file xxx" that happens exactly once annually?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: There's no mention that the run times will exceed 24 hours. Indeed, my initial reading of the specification allows you to implement 1 hour maximum time resolution meaning you can potentially just use 60 slots.

Comment: @slebetman: 1 hour would be 3600 slots (not the it makes any huge difference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a priority queue (with the priority based on the next execution time) to hold the tasks to execute. When you're done executing a task, you sleep until the time for the task at the front of the queue. When a task comes due, you remove and execute it, then (if its recurring) compute the next time it needs to run, and insert it back into the priority queue based on its next run time.

This way you have one sleep active at any given time. Insertions and removals have logarithmic complexity, so it remains efficient even if you have millions of tasks (e.g., inserting into a priority queue that has a million tasks should take about 20 comparisons in the worst case).

There is one point that can be a little tricky: if the execution thread is waiting until a particular time to execute the item at the head of the queue, and you insert a new item that goes at the head of the queue, ahead of the item that was previously there, you need to wake up the thread so it can re-adjust its sleep time for the item that's now at the head of the queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I answered the exact same thing on my test today except I totally forgot about the edge case you mentioned in the last paragraph which I realised while rethinking about it

Answer (score -1):

We encountered this same issue while designing [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com), an open source project for scheduling triggered callbacks. In the end, we ended up writing our own priority queue class (we called ours a `ScheduledDictionary`) to handle the use case you outlined in your question. As a free, open source project, the complete source code (C#, in this case) is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee). I'd recommend that you check it out.